# How to deploy webservice on jboss 4.0.4 application server hosted on solaris 10 with a specific port?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jboss, solaris

I am totally new to JBOSS 4.0.4 app server and Solaris 10.
I have developed my webservice WAR file with Eclipse and need to deploy it on my remote jboss web server (version 4.0.4) hosted on Solaris (version 10) and need to assign port 8088 to it.
I mean my clients need to access my web service with: http://test.com:8088/myWebService?wsdl

How can I achieve this?
What configurations should I do in order to make it possible?
One of my friend told me that JBOSS version 4.0.4 hosts every http request with just one port number, i.e all JSPs and webservices would have same port number which is defined in /export/home/app/jboss/server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/server.xml
on my development server the server.xml looks like following:

```
<Server>
  <Service name="jboss.web"
  className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.StandardService">
  <!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
  <Connector port="8090" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
     maxThreads="250" strategy="ms" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
     emptySessionPath="true"
     enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
     connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"/>
  <!-- Add this option to the connector to avoid problems with 
      .NET clients that don't implement HTTP/1.1 correctly 
     restrictedUserAgents="^.*MS Web Services Client Protocol 1.1.4322.*$"
  -->
  <!-- A AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
  <Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
     emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" 
     protocol="AJP/1.3"/>
  <Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost">
     <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossSecurityMgrRealm"
        certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
        allRolesMode="authOnly"
        />
     </Host>
  </Engine>
```

Is it right?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer i guess: Actually jboss 4.0.4 is using tomcat as it's webserver and it contains server.xml which is configurable to be listen to different ports as described in this article:
http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-connectors

Actually I should have defined different connector and engine element in server.xml and it is done.
As I said, I modified my server.xml as following:

```
    <Server>

  <!-- Use a custom version of StandardService that allows the
   connectors to be started independent of the normal lifecycle
   start to allow web apps to be deployed before starting the
   connectors.
   -->
  <Service name="jboss.web"
     className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.StandardService">

    <!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
    <Connector port="8090" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       maxThreads="250" strategy="ms" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
       emptySessionPath="true"
       enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
       connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"/>

    <!-- Add this option to the connector to avoid problems with 
          .NET clients that don't implement HTTP/1.1 correctly 
         restrictedUserAgents="^.*MS Web Services Client Protocol 1.1.4322.*$"
      -->

    <!-- A AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443"
       protocol="AJP/1.3"/>

    <!-- SSL/TLS Connector configuration using the admin devl guide keystore
      <Connector port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
           maxThreads="100" strategy="ms" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           emptySessionPath="true"
           scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
           keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/chap8.keystore"
           keystorePass="rmi+ssl" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
      -->

    <Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossSecurityMgrRealm"
         certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
         allRolesMode="authOnly"
            />

      <Host name="localhost"
         autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false" deployXML="false">

      </Host>

    </Engine>

  </Service>

  <Service name="jboss.webservice"
    className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.StandardService">

    <!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
    <Connector port="8099" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       maxThreads="250" strategy="ms" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
       emptySessionPath="true"
       enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
       connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"/>

    <Engine name="jboss.webservice" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossSecurityMgrRealm"
         certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
         allRolesMode="authOnly"
            />

      <Host name="localhost"
         autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false" deployXML="false">
<Context path="/"></Context>
      </Host>

    </Engine>

  </Service>

</Server>
```

As you can see, I have added a new Service tag and named it "jboss.webservice". I think the rest of the xml code is declarative and no other explanation is needed to understand.
Anyway dont forget to kill jboss process in SOLARIS and Run it again.
I tried these commands and after jboss was up again i was able to telnet to that port. :)

```
#ps -ef | grep 0.0.0
//here I get the process id of jboss, assume i get 1234
#kill -9 1234
//here I kill it
#cd /export/home/app/jboss/bin
//here i go to my jboss bin directory to run it
#nohup ./run.sh &
//here jboss is run
//now telnet
# telnet myIpadd 8099
```

that's it.
hope it helps.